# After login the `rest-auth`, how to return more information?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-auth

I use `django-rest-auth` in my Django project.

After login the `rest-auth/login/`, how to return more information?

In the `rest-auth/login/`, when I login the user, it returns a `key`.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

I want to also return the user's information, how can I get this?

Comment: Use request.user or print and check.

Comment: @AnupYadav I use the third `rest-auth` lib, there is no View for me. the View is controlled by `rest-auth`.

Comment: Either you can use https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/10/24/how-to-add-social-login-to-django.html To get all information or you can build custom library for each OAuth for google oauth https://github.com/anupy/google-oauth For other service providers you can use your own (custom)

Comment: https://github.com/PhilipGarnero/django-rest-framework-social-oauth2 This one is also seems good to me

Answer (score 14, accepted):

At last, I get my solution:

```
class TokenSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serializer for Token model.
    """
    user = UserInfoSerializer(many=False, read_only=True)  # this is add by myself.
    class Meta:
        model = TokenModel
        fields = ('key', 'user')   # there I add the `user` field ( this is my need data ).
```

In the project `settings.py`, add the `TOKEN_SERIALIZER` like bellow:

```
REST_AUTH_SERIALIZERS = {
    ...
    'TOKEN_SERIALIZER': 'Project.path.to.TokenSerializer',
}
```

Now I get my need data:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51431768/how-do-i-also-get-user-data-with-token-key-in-http-response-to-django-rest-aut)

You can override the default `TokenSerializer` with a custom serializer that will include users.

in a file say yourapp/serializers.py

```
from django.conf import settings

from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_auth.models import TokenModel
from rest_auth.utils import import_callable
from rest_auth.serializers import UserDetailsSerializer as DefaultUserDetailsSerializer

# This is to allow you to override the UserDetailsSerializer at any time.
# If you're sure you won't, you can skip this and use DefaultUserDetailsSerializer directly
rest_auth_serializers = getattr(settings, 'REST_AUTH_SERIALIZERS', {})
UserDetailsSerializer = import_callable(
    rest_auth_serializers.get('USER_DETAILS_SERIALIZER', DefaultUserDetailsSerializer)
)

class CustomTokenSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserDetailsSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = TokenModel
        fields = ('key', 'user', )
```

and in your app settings use rest-auth configuration to override the default class

```
yourapp/settings.py

REST_AUTH_SERIALIZERS = {
    'TOKEN_SERIALIZER': 'yourapp.serializers.CustomTokenSerializer' # import path to CustomTokenSerializer defined above.
}
```