# How do i also get user data with token "Key" in http response to django rest_auth login endpoint?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I am very new to working with django. i have  developed an API for user Registration, Login and Logout with Django Rest-Auth Using Custom User Model extending AbstractUser.

When i call POST on Login API endpoint using credential, i get token in response, Please check below screenshot.

[POST on Login API Endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkqAe.png)

I also need to get Logged in User data. how do i do that!?

Any help would do.
TIA.

Comment: If you don't want token then why  are you using this?

Comment: oh Sorry, i made a mistake. I have edited my question now. I need token and user data as well.

Comment: I think you have to override those classes and functions

Comment: make another request to an endpoint that returns `request.user` by passing this token as Authorization Header

Answer (score 2):

You can override the default `TokenSerializer` with a custom serializer that will include users.

in a file say yourapp/model.py

```
from django.conf import settings

from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_auth.models import TokenModel
from rest_auth.utils import import_callable
from rest_auth.serializers import UserDetailsSerializer as DefaultUserDetailsSerializer

# This is to allow you to override the UserDetailsSerializer at any time.
# If you're sure you won't, you can skip this and use DefaultUserDetailsSerializer directly
rest_auth_serializers = getattr(settings, 'REST_AUTH_SERIALIZERS', {})
UserDetailsSerializer = import_callable(
    rest_auth_serializers.get('USER_DETAILS_SERIALIZER', DefaultUserDetailsSerializer)
)

class CustomTokenSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserDetailsSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = TokenModel
        fields = ('key', 'user', )
```

and in your app settings use rest-auth configuration to override the default class

yourapp/settings.py

```
.
.
.
.

REST_AUTH_SERIALIZERS = {
    'TOKEN_SERIALIZER': 'yourapp.models.CustomTokenSerializer' # import path to CustomTokenSerializer defined above.
}
```

Comment: This work perfectly for me just that the 'CustomTokenSerializer' serializer class is likely to be in the serializers.py than models.py. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement your custom view and serializer to do that.

First, you create your serializer for response with key and user data.

Since we don't have info on your model, this is just basic example:

```
class MySerializer(serializes.ModelSerializer):

    key = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_key(self, obj):
         return create_token(obj)

    class Meta:
        model=  User
        fields = ( 'id', 'username', 'key', )
```

here the get_key can generate your token ( obj will be instance of your user model )

Then, I would suggest to look at how django-rest-auth implements `LoginView` which you use to get the token now.

And you create new view and take inspiration from LoginView implementation to understand how to obtain the token. And you use the serializer to create response you want.